# C# Dynamic If arugment

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Building a WPF application in C#
I have 5 check boxes and when one or more is selected I want the argument of a it statement to change dynamically.
For example, I have Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu & Fri as the check boxes.
If user selects Mon, Wed, & Fri then I want the argument for a if statement to change to reflect that.
I don't want to make numerous different if statements.
Here is a sample I wrote, but the if statement is wrong obviously

```
string passArg = "";

        if(check_mon.IsChecked == true)
        {
            passArg = "passArg == \"Mon\"";
        }

        if(passArg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("RAN");
        }
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: Do you want a switch statement?

Comment: Only 5 if statement is enough. You build up your string using += operator. Like `passArg+="Thu"` and `passArg+="Fri"` etc

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary and how would you subtract when unchecked? You can't just `-=` "unconcatenate" strings...

Comment: @Tinwor you can't overload operators for existing classes. And you can't derive from `string` because it's sealed.

Comment: Right, I need to sleep. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @GwynBleidd thats right. How ever you can generate this string over and over when ever you need it. It shouldn't be problem unless this variable is used frequently

Answer (score 2):

You can fire an event when the checkbox is `Checked` or `Unchecked` and in this method you can set or unset your stuff.
For example in your xaml form:

```
<CheckBox Checked="Checked" Unchecked="UnChecked"/>
```

And then create the events:

```
private void UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //Checked, enable, disable or do whatever you want
}
private void Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //Checked, enable, disable or do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a value in a list:

```
List<string> checked = new List<string>()

if (check_mon.IsChecked)
{
   checked.Add("Mon");
}

if (checked.Contains(passArg))
{
   MessageBox.Show("RAN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as simply as you would like.  You *can* generate code dynamically but it's overkill in this case. All you need is:

```
bool isChecked = false;

if(check_mon.IsChecked && passArg == "Mon")
{
    isChecked = true;
}
...

if(isChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("RAN");
}
```

> I don't want to make numerous different if statements.

Well, you *could* put the checkboxes in a loop, set the `Tag` or some other property and compare that against `pasArg` but I tend to go with the *simplest* solution that *works* first then focus on making it *better*.  You may find that you spend more time trying to come up with a clever solution (that you may not understand later) when 7 `if` statements would work just fine.

Comment: But I have 5 different days. A user could select any combo of days. This would require me to have numerous different if statements to predict every single combo

Comment: @DhavalDesai Your example only shows one day in `passArg`. If you need to compare against any combination of days then show what `passArg` would be in that case.  In any case you shouldn't have to check for "every single combination" in separate `if` statements.